# How to integrate Spring Boot 3 with Keycloak SAML?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, saml-2.0, spring-saml

Im working on Spring Boot 3 migration.
I had Keycloak SAML working on Spring Boot 2.7.x.

I had follwed https://www.codecentric.de/wissens-hub/blog/secure-spring-boot-app-saml-keycloak for the integraion.

Now in the latest Spring Boot there are changes to the Spring Security and the deprecated classes and methods are removed.

The Spring-SAML extention used in Spring Boot 2.7.x no longer work.
I want to setup Keycloak SAML authentication on my Spring Boot 3 application.

Is there any sample working example or has anyone worked on it?

Comment: Do you have any solutions for this question?

Comment: No, we decided to go with openId for now.